# Is it possible to change fastCGI activityTimeout via PHP on IIS?

Tags: php, iis, fastcgi

I'm curious if it's possible to change activityTimeout via PHP when I'm using fastCGI on IIS. I know that I can change PHP.ini values via `ini_set()`, but I'm not able to change this one. So is it even possible, or I'm crying over a dead grave?

Comment: For the running script you can use [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

Comment: @harrymc yes, this sets `max_execution_time` but i need to set `activityTimeout` for fastCGI

Answer (score 0):

The following code samples add a FastCGI application for PHP, set the instanceMaxRequests attribute to "10000," and set the PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS environment variable to "10000." Each sample also adds a global FastCGI handler mapping for PHP files to IIS and specifies the full path to a FastCGI executable file.

> appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /+"[fullPath='C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe',arguments='',maxInstances='4',idleTimeout='300',activityTimeout='30',requestTimeout='90',instanceMaxRequests='10000',protocol='NamedPipe',flushNamedPipe='False']" /commit:apphost

Don't forget to change activityTimeout and path to PHP in an example above.

> appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /+"[fullPath='C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe'].environmentVariables.[name='PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS',value='10000']" /commit:apphost
>
> appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/handlers /+"[name='PHP-FastCGI',path='*.php',verb='GET,HEAD,POST',modules='FastCgiModule',scriptProcessor='C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe',resourceType='Either',requireAccess='Script']" /commit:apphost